# android automate testing orientation change

Tags: android, testing, orientation

I spend many time testing orientation changes, going back, changing again etc etc..checking if fragment are loaded correctly..

has anyone think about a process to test that issues or use a tool for that?

thanks

Comment: what's wrong with tilting the device?

Comment: Not sure from which knowledge level you are coming. Relevant to give you a good answer: Do you know what unit/blackbox testing is *(e.g. with junit or robotium)*?

Comment: then use robotium. solo.setActivityOrientation(Solo.LANDSCAPE);

Comment: the problem is that i want to test to several screen sizes and in this case i need to see how it works in each differet screen...is this possible with any tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Spoon](http://square.github.io/spoon/) test runner. It will run your instrumentation tests on all connected devices and can also make screenshots during the test to help you see the results visually.

Answer (score 7):

Using Robotium, you can change the orientation by simply calling:

```
solo.setActivityOrientation(Solo.LANDSCAPE);
```

or in JUnit:

```
activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

I'm not really aware of an existing method of automatically testing with several screen sizes, but it would be easy enough to manually run the test using a different AVD if you configure AVDs for each screen resolution you want to test with. You could probably start various emulators and run the tests all from the command line on each emulator using something like the following (if you're using a Unix like operating system or Cygwin):

```
for i in avd_1 avd_2 avd_3
do 
   emulator -avd $i &
   PID=$!
   adb wait-for-device
   adb -e install path/to/your/app.apk
   kill $PID
done
```

where avd_1, avd_2, etc. are replaced by your android virtual device names for the devices with the different screen resolutions.

Comment: Thanks. But there's a problem...more than an emulator and my laptop collapses :)

Comment: I've updated the example above to store the process id in PID and kill the emulator between each run so you only have one emulator running at a time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your unit & HMI tests on multiples emulators with different Screen size and resolution, the best thing to do is to setup a [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Home) with the [android emulator plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin).

It allows you to define matrix jobs and check if your tests are ok on several platforms:

[image: jenkins matrix]

It will be painfull to set up but the benefits are really great!